java android listview setOnLongClickListener
To function long click, the override function is changed and there are only out of date references.
I am also use click listner.
but the onLongClick override funcion don't have position variable.
Can you give me recent information to make long click?
`
listView.setLongClickable(true);


listView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        
        return false;
    }

});

`
I tried to used old codes in blogs. but the old override function is not exist any more.
And android document don't describe detail about the long click for java.

set your position as a tag for view when view is created, and read the position using view.gettag in long click listener
    view.setTag(position);
    
    int pos = view.getTag()


I would recommend you to use RecyclerView which is newer and performs better than Listview on large datasets.
However if you wanna keep using ListView then you want to use its setOnItemLongClickListener to listen long clicks on the list items. The following snippet shows how it is used:
ListView yourListView;

yourListView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

yourListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Here you will have all the information you need:
        // parent is listview, view is item view that is clicked,
        // position is the item's position in the adapter, id is given automatically I think
    }
});


set your position as a tag for view when creating a view in listview adapter, and read the position using view.gettag in long click listener view.setTag(position); int pos = view.getTag()

Thank you, how to set position as a tag? I want to know what menu is clicked long, the item's position.

in listadapter get view method set position to view being returned using view.setTag(position);

the listViewAdapter.getView takes (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent), do i pass  local int variable to the parameter of position?

pass position to view using view,setTag(position) being returned in getview

and on longclick listener call view.getTag to findout the item cliked

ListView has a setOnItemLongClickListener using which you can get the position
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return true;
    }
}); 

